# mysql REGEXP not matching

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a regular expression intended to catch phone numbers within a string

```
/[1,+ ().-][\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}/
```

I try to query my MySql database for this regex using this query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `everything`.`instances_meta` AS m
WHERE
    `meta.value` REGEXP "[1,+][\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}"
```

I can confirm the regex, itself, does what I want from testing it [here](https://regex101.com/r/qhr4kQ/1) but it does not pull any matches when queried. Something tells me I am missing some sort of expression to say "anywhere in the string". I would specify the regex engine but I am unsure of what MySql uses.

Comment: Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing a status report. (You are unsure what MySQL uses for a Regular Expression engine. That is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual, which is available.)  But what I don't see is an actual *question*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
"[1,+][[:blank:].-][0-9]{3}[[:blank:].-][0-9]{3}[[:blank:].-][0-9]{4}"
```

as MySQL `REGEXP` does not support `\s` and `\d`.

The `[:blank:]` matches spaces and tabs, and `[0-9]` matches any ASCII digit.

Comment: FYI: MySQL `REGEXP` is not anchoring the pattern, and looks for a match anywhere inside the string (called a *partial match*). MySQL uses a  POSIX regex flavor, a very limited set of regular expression patterns, however, the POSIX character classes are also fine to use. Note you might want to use `[[:digit:]]` instead of `\d`, or `[:space:]` instead of `[:blank:]` -  test and see which is performing best.

Comment: Where do you find this information about what `REGEXP` support in MySQL? I'm having the same problem and the documentation not mention these limitations.

Comment: @Dherik What is the MySQL version you are using? Older versions before MySql v.8 used a POSIX regex engine so you may check all POSIX regex related reference.

Comment: I'm using the `5.7` version

Comment: So, the main part is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html. The rest is at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html

Comment: Thankyou, didn't realize \d needed to be [0-9]